# How to post ID of span using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, this, attr

I need post ID of span using ajax, but it doesnt work :D `alert($(this).attr("id"))` work so why doesnt work ajax?

```
$(".nav-item").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "load.php",
        data: {
            page: $(this).attr("id");
        }
    }).done(function(result) {
        $("#main").html(result);
    });
});
```

Comment: Need more specific debugging details than a simple statement *"doesnt work"*. Start by inspecting request in browser dev tools network tab to see if request is even made, what gets sent, status, response etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If thats exact copy of your code then remove that semicolon after page:

```
data: {
    page: $(this).attr("id"); <---- remove this semicolon
 }
```

...otherwise, your code is correct, here is an example (check console > network requests > payload sent by request):
https://jsfiddle.net/co6yupzg/